# Any Idea how to uninstall .MSI with a password in the argument parameter?

Tags: powershell, uninstallation

I am still pretty new to PowerShell and I am trying to create a PS script that uninstalls a program remotely, however it doesn't seem to be working, it runs fine with no error messages, but just doesn't seem to uninstall the app. I am sure I might be doing something completely wrong... Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Code below:

```
$Password = "1234"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName TEST `
-ScriptBlock {
$product = Get-WmiObject win32_product | where{$_.name -eq "Program Name"}
$product.IdentifyingNumber
Start-Process "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" `
-ArgumentList "/x $($product.IdentifyingNumber) PASSWORD=$Password /quiet /noreboot" -Wait }
```

Comment: Remove `/quiet` if you want it to make noise on failure :)

Comment: Good point just checking now 

Comment: Seems to be running indefinitely, with nothing appearing on the remote PC.....

Comment: Add a test to see if you indeed have received a valid `$product` from the `Get-WmiObject` call and only proceed if that is the case.

Comment: if you were to run the command without using PowerShell (eg. "msiexec /x {9e42df27-2b47-4c30-9635-c51e0f4b5c3f} PASSWORD=<inpur password> /quiet /noreboot", does it uninstall successfully? Does the MSI support the switch PASSWORD?

Comment: Also tack on /L*v c:\product_uninstall.txt to output a verbose log as to why if fails.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the strange indentation in your code I didn't see it at first, but the thing is that variable `$Password` is unknown in the scriptblock, unless you either scope it with `using:` or send it as parameter in the `ArgumentsList` parameter of the scriptblock and add a `param()` block in there.

Also, as commented, only proceed with the Start-Process command if you have checked that the `Get-WmiObject` call actually returned a valid product object.

Try

Using the [using:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#scope-modifiers) scope modifier

```
$Password = "1234"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName TEST -ScriptBlock {
    $product = Get-WmiObject win32_product | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Program Name"}
    if ($product) {
        $argList = "/x $($product.IdentifyingNumber) PASSWORD=$using:Password /quiet /noreboot"
        Start-Process "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $argList -Wait 
    }
}
```

or use a `param()` block in the scriptblock

```
$Password = "1234"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName TEST -ScriptBlock {
    param( $Password )
    $product = Get-WmiObject win32_product | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Program Name"}
    if ($product) {
        $argList = "/x $($product.IdentifyingNumber) PASSWORD=$Password /quiet /noreboot"
        Start-Process "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $argList -Wait 
    }
} -ArgumentList $Password
```

<sup>You may consider using the newer `Get-CimInstance` cmdlet instead of `Get-WmiObject`</sup>